# static short[9][9] getRandomBoard();

Tags: c++, c

I tried to return short[9][9] for soduko game
static short[9][9] getRandomBoard();

```
static short[9][9] getRandomBoard()
{
    short board[9][9];

    bla bla bla.....................
    bla bla bla.....................
    bla bla bla.....................

    return board;
}
```

and i got an error:
Error excpected a ';'

Comment: Use std::array or vector.

Comment: [tag:c++] != [tag:c]

Comment: c-array are not assignable.

Comment: Do not create functions that allocate memory and return a pointer.  That is setting yourself up for a memory leak.  You should instead set up this function to take in a pointer to an already-allocated block of memory and populate the information there.

Comment: @Sildoreth The `board` array is allocated on the stack and will be automatically destroyed when the function returns. The bad behavior here is that you'll be returning a pointer to that destroyed data.

Comment: @Sildoreth: Allocating memory and  returning a pointer to has the considerable advantage that the function can determine how big the array needs to be. Yes, it can leak memory if the caller doesn't release it -- so make sure the caller releases it.  Having the caller pass a pointer to an already allocated block *can* be a good solution, but only if the caller knows how big the array will need to be.

Comment: A C or C++ function cannot return an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `board` is an array allocated of off of the stack frame which goes away once the function is returned. If you wish to return a contiguous array allocated off of the heap do the following:

```
static short(* getRandomBoard())[9] {
  short (*board)[9] = (short (*)[9]) malloc(9*9*sizeof(short));
  ...
  board[i][j] = 3;
  ...
  return board;
}
```

Just remember to `free(board)` when done with the array to avoid a leak.

Better yet, redefine your function to pass `board` as an argument (i.e., let the caller worry about allocation):

```
void getRandomBoard(short board[9][9]) {
   ....
}
```

This way `board` could be allocated off the stack (no need to free), the heap, or statically.

It would be better to use `<array>` if you are using c++

```
array<array<short,9>,9> getRandomBoard() {
   array<array<short,9>,9> board;
   ...
   board[i][j] = 3;
   ...
   return board;
}
```

If you want to stick with C, the following link will tell you all the ways you can represent a 2D array in C:

http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs330/lectures/linear_algebra/matrix/matrix.pdf

Answer (score 2):

### Problem 1

First off, your declaration of the function needs to be changed.

```
static short[9][9] getRandomBoard()
```

It should be

```
static short** getRandomBoard()
```

### Problem 2

The stack level for `getRandomBoard` owns the variable named `board`.  When the stack level for your function disappears, so does the 2D array for the variable `board`.  This means that you are returning a pointer to a memory location that is no longer valid.

The easy way to remember this and avoid problems in the future is that if you use `new`, then data is created on the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP); otherwise, it is created on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

The bare minimum changes to make your example work would give you this:

```
static short** getRandomBoard() {
  //Allocate 2D array on the heap, not on the stack
  short** board = new short*[9];
  //Create 2nd level of 2D array with arrays allocated on the heap
  for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    board[i] = new short[9];
  }
  //Populate 2D array here
  return board;
}
```

That being said, it is bad practice (if you can avoid it) to have a function allocate memory and return a pointer to the allocated memory.  This tends to lead to [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).  Instead, you should have your function take in the array as a parameter.

```
static void populateRandomBoard(short board[9][9]) {
  //Populate board here
}
```

And then use the function like this:

```
static int main() {
  short board[9][9];
  populateRandomBoard(board);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C-array are not assignable and can't be returned from function.

The easier is to use a structure

```
struct Board
{
    short numbers[9][9];
};

Board CreateRandomBoard()
{
    Board board;

    // Fill board values
    // board.numbers[i][j] = value;
    // ...

    return board;
}
```

and you avoid memory management.